# Is visa type "D" considered Schengen?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, denmark

I received a Danish long-term visa type "D" in January 2017. I lived in Denmark for 3 months and was able to travel within the Schengen area with the type D visa (also I had work and residence permit).

Currently, I live in the USA and I'm traveling again to Denmark for a short-term visit (20 days).
Hence, I am applying for a Schengen visa.
On the online application, there is a question.

"Have you had any Schengen visas issued during the past three years? " YES/NO

I guess, my answer should be "YES", because of my previous type D visa. Also, if I answer "YES", I need not provide my biometrics since they were collected when I applied for type D visa in 2017.

Please help me if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit ambiguous, “D visa“ is Schengen terminology for a long-stay visa but those are in fact national visas, issued under a different set of rules separate from the rules controlling the Schengen system.

All this is however quite theoretical, in practice there is no harm in answering “yes“. It's always best to ensure you do not appear to be hiding information and an earlier long-stay visa is more likely to help your application than anything else.

However, you should not assume you will not have to enroll your biometrics again. At the moment, the VIS, the system used by Schengen countries to store these data does not cover long-stay visas ([in fact there are plans to allow that](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-18-1745_en.htm)) so the data you submitted in 2017 might not be reusable. It certainly would not be for any other country than Denmark.

Comment: Yes, this is a great response, and I agree with everything you have mentioned. 

Even I am not clear with the "Biometrics" requirement and I am not sure if I can post my documents or visit VFS global.

I called VFS global multiple times and they say VISA type D is issued by a Schengen state. Hence, biometrics recording is not required.  But I am not sure if the operator knows these details well.  If they use two different databases for national VISAs and Schengen VISAs, there is unlikely that my data will be in the Schengen database. This left me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, type D Schengen visa is a Schengen visa. You should answer "Yes".

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that.